# How to update tag in a file by using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a configuration file which is (test.properties)

File includes:

```
<a>aa</a>
<b>bb</b>
<c>ccc</c>
<d>dddd</d>
<Test>Yes</Test>
```

I want to replace a value of "Nope" in test.properties file by using powershell.

```
Existing : <Test>Nope<Test>

 AFter Update it should be 

        <Test>Yes<Test>
```

How can i replace this value by using powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use replace! Below code will read the content in the file and replace your test tag with the new value and then write the content back to the same file

```
(Get-Content yourfile.xml).replace("<Test>Nope<Test>", "<Test>Yes<Test>") | Set-Content yourfile.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I want to set 'Yes' value by using paramater how can i set it? For example i have a parameter which is $value='Yes' and i want to set like <Test>$value<Test>

Comment: Np! Then you can use string interpolation, try it like this '<Test>$($value)<Test>'

Comment: It doesnt work for me: (       Comment: (Get-Content yourfile.xml).replace('<Test>Nope<Test>',  '<Test>$($value)<Test>') | Set-Content yourfile.xml  so output is: <Test>$value<Test>

Comment: @Ukchat the $value is restricted. Try with $custValue. Also, use double qoutes "<test>$($custValue)</test>"

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the RegEx based `-replace` operator in contrast to the `.replace()` method used by Markus Höglund.

```
-replace "(?<=<(Test)>).*?(?=</\1)",$custValue
```

It doesn't care about the text it replaces using nonconsuming [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) specfying  the text before and after (The \1 repeats the grouped `(Test)` in the lookahead).

```
(get-Content .\test.properties) -replace "(?<=<(Test)>).*?(?=</\1)",$custValue|
set-Content .\test.properties
```

BTW isn't the closing tag preceeded by a `/` ?